# How to run multiple instances of requests_html's webpage renderer with multiprocessing/threading?

Tags: python, web-scraping, multiprocessing

I want to fetch a link from a webpage which is rendered by the server so I need to use requests_html and render webpage to extract the link from it.

Now assume I want 10 links from 10 webpages, it works one by one, first it renders the webpage and then extracts the link which is time consuming

What I want to do is extract all the links by running different instances of that function with multiprocessing/threading at the same time

So I tried the following way:

```
   download_links = []

   def getDownloadLinks(url):
       session = HTMLSession()
       page = session.get(url)
       page.html.render(timeout=0)
       link = page.find('#zmovie-view', first=True).find('video', first=True).attrs['src']
       download_links.append(link)
 

    links = ['https://animehd47.com/jujutsu-kaisen-tv/s2-m1/', 'https://animehd47.com/jujutsu-kaisen-tv/s2-m2/', 'https://animehd47.com/jujutsu-kaisen-tv/s2-m3/', 'https://animehd47.com/jujutsu-kaisen-tv/s2-m4/', 'https://animehd47.com/jujutsu-kaisen-tv/s2-m5/', 'https://animehd47.com/jujutsu-kaisen-tv/s2-m6/', 'https://animehd47.com/jujutsu-kaisen-tv/s2-m7/', 'https://animehd47.com/jujutsu-kaisen-tv/s2-m8/', 'https://animehd47.com/jujutsu-kaisen-tv/s2-m9/', 'https://animehd47.com/jujutsu-kaisen-tv/s2-m10/']
    
    threads = []
    for i in range(len(links)):
        process = multiprocessing.Process(target=getDownloadLinks, args=(links[i],))
        process.start()
        threads.append(process)

    for t in threads:
        t.join()
```

But it returns nothing instead throws multiple errors.
I looked up at Google and what I was able to get is its related to asyncio, that it never gets to finish its loop iteration successfully

What exactly is the problem?

Comment: What errors is this code throwing? Is it actually to do with the HTMLsession or is it something else. Also what is the "links" list in this context? It isn't defined anywhere in your example code. Please update the question with a minimal reproducible example so I can help to solve your problem.

Comment: @CmdCoder858 Sorry for late response. The error is the "Future exception was never retrieved
future: <Future finished exception=NetworkError('Protocol error (Target.sendMessageToTarget): No session with given id')>
pyppeteer.errors.NetworkError: Protocol error (Target.sendMessageToTarget): No session with given id" and its returning an empty list. Also I've updated the question with links list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From my testing this code seems to be the best solution to your problem:

```
import multiprocessing
from requests_html import HTMLSession


def getDownloadLinks(url, returnvar, i):
    try:
        session = HTMLSession()
        page = session.get(url)
        page.html.render(timeout=0)
        link = page.html.find('#zmovie-view', first=True).find('video', first=True).attrs['src']
        returnvar[str(i)] = link
        page.close()
        session.close()
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)


links = ['https://animehd47.com/jujutsu-kaisen-tv/s2-m1/', 'https://animehd47.com/jujutsu-kaisen-tv/s2-m2/',
         'https://animehd47.com/jujutsu-kaisen-tv/s2-m3/', 'https://animehd47.com/jujutsu-kaisen-tv/s2-m4/',
         'https://animehd47.com/jujutsu-kaisen-tv/s2-m5/', 'https://animehd47.com/jujutsu-kaisen-tv/s2-m6/',
         'https://animehd47.com/jujutsu-kaisen-tv/s2-m7/', 'https://animehd47.com/jujutsu-kaisen-tv/s2-m8/',
         'https://animehd47.com/jujutsu-kaisen-tv/s2-m9/', 'https://animehd47.com/jujutsu-kaisen-tv/s2-m10/']


if __name__ == '__main__':
    threads = []
    manager = multiprocessing.Manager()
    returndict = manager.dict()
    for i in range(len(links)):
        try:
            process = multiprocessing.Process(target=getDownloadLinks, args=(links[i], returndict, i))
            process.start()
            threads.append(process)
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)
    for t in threads:
        t.join()
    print(returndict)
```

This code uses a multiprocessing manager to return the values from the worker function properly and it doesn't seem to raise the errors anymore, for me at least. Hopefully this helps and if you have any questions then make sure to comment below.

Comment: Yes It works!! Many Thanks for your time and testing. Please could you explain in more detail what exactly the problem was with my code and how does that fix. I recently started using multiprocessing so I'm in for learning more than getting this one working. Thanks again!!

Comment: What I'm able to understand is that I needed to close the session created after every function execution. right?

Comment: Yes, I believe that the reason it was throwing those errors was because the connection wasn’t closed and so timed out, though I’m not really certain as I couldn’t find much documentation on the error online.

Comment: Yeah I too wasn't able to find much about it. And using global dict and adding to it was a problem too?

Comment: Well the manager dictionary was just used by me to make sure you could actually retrieve the data from the worker processes. It's not directly related to the problem but I used it because I couldn't get a normal list to properly retrieve the data.

Comment: Okay.. Thanks again!! I really appreciate your help